# insert into a mysql database timestamp

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, insert

I have a part in my python script that I need to insert some data into a table on a mysql database example below:

```
insert_data = "INSERT into test (test_date,test1,test2) values (%s,%s,%s)"
cur.execute(insert_data,(test_date,test1,test2))
db.commit()
db.close()
```

I have a couple of questions what is incorrect with this syntax and how is possible to change the VALUES to timestamp instead of %s for string? Note the column names in the database are the same as the data stored in the variables in my script.

THanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

try this:

```
import MySQLdb
import time
import datetime

ts = time.time()
timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host= "localhost",
              user="root",
              passwd="newpassword",
              db="db1")
x = conn.cursor()

try:
   x.execute("""INSERT into test (test_date,test1,test2) values(%s,%s,%s)""",(timestamp,test1,test2))
   conn.commit()
except:
   conn.rollback()

conn.close()
```

Comment: Thanks what about the date? I need it to be inserted in this format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

Comment: @StevenWilson please accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 15):

Timestamp creating can be done in one line, no need to use time.time(), just:

```
from datetime import datetime

timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: You forgot to import some stuff

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the database `NOW()` function, e.g.

```py
timestamp="NOW()"
insert_data = "INSERT into test (test_date,test1,test2) values (%s,%s,%s)"
cur.execute(insert_data,(test_date,test1,test2,timestamp))
db.commit()
db.close()
```

Comment: it doesn't work with %s placeholders, because it will throw the error "Incorrect datetime value", it's better to use datetime module as mentioned above.